# How to add the tags to existing pdf file?

Tags: pdf, itext, tagged-pdf

Could anyone explain how to add the tags to the existing pdf file using iText library in java, 
is there any sample code for adding the tags to pdf files ?

Comment: Any updates on this? @Balaji Ravi . I too am working on the same problem?